# Conflicting msys2-runtime and catgets

Tags: windows, mingw-w64, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I am installing 64-bit version of MSYS2 on my sistem. After installing, I run MINGW64 for the first time following the instruction on [this](http://www.msys2.org/) official website. However, after I run `pacman -Syu`, I got this message:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 mingw32 is up to date
 mingw64 is up to date
 msys is up to date
:: Starting core system upgrade...
warning: terminate other MSYS2 programs before proceeding
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: msys2-runtime and catgets are in conflict. Remove catgets? [y/N]
```

It said that msys2-runtime and catgets are in conflict and asked me if I want to remove catgets. Any suggestion of what should I do in this step?

Comment: `pacman -R catgets` `pacman -R libcatgets` helped me according to https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/1147#issuecomment-373946815

Answer (score 4):

You should answer `y` to remove `catgets`.  The `msys2-runtime` package is very important and you should want to upgrade it to the latest version.