# How to resolve conflict after installing msys2 and running "pacman -Syuu"?

Tags: c, mingw, msys, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I have installed latest release of msys2 (msys2-x86_64-20161025). When I am running `pacman -Syuu` I am getting:

[image]

and if I answer `y` I get after:

[image]

What should I answer these questions?

*About running `pacman -Syuu` after installation of msys2 I read here: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/MSYS2-installation*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conflicting msys2-runtime and catgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334489/conflicting-msys2-runtime-and-catgets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer "yes" to everything, and/or remove catgets beforehand with `pacman -R libcatgets`.

[Relevant support ticket](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/1147). They seem to be in the process of removing all dependencies to libcatgets.